# how to write Retain in SQL

Tags: sql

Suppose, there is a table with 3 columns: record_id, month, status. The SAS code which am trying to replicate in SQL using windows function is as follows:

```
data t1;
set t;
by record_id;
retain x 1;
if first.record_id then x= 1;
if not first.record_id then; if status= lag1(status) then x+ 1; else x= 1;
run;
```

Can somebody help me to create this x variable in SQL

Sample data is: the first 3 are input variables and last one is the required variable 'x'

```
1 201801 closed 1
1 201802 open   1
1 201803 open   2
1 201804 closed 1
1 201805 closed 2
1 201806 closed 3
1 201807 open   1
2 201801 closed 1
2 201802 open   1
```

Comment: @Neha . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the one you are using.  In addition, your question makes no sense.  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that you want to enumerate adjacent (by month) values of status for a given record.

One of the crucial differences between a SAS dataset and a SQL table is that tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, whatever column is used to order the SAS dataset needs to be explicitly part of the query.  I am guessing the ordering is `recordid`, `month`, `status`.

This problem is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  You can determine the "islands" of adjacent values that are the same using the difference of row numbers:

So, the query is:

```
select t1.*,
       row_number() over (partition by recordid, status, (seqnum - sequm_2) order by month) as x
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by recordid order by month) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by recordid, status order by month) as seqnum_2
      from t1
     ) t1
```

Also, SAS `proc sql` does not support the (SQL standard) `row_number()` function.  However, most other databases do.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, i just made change to the line : row_number() over (partition by recordid, status, (seqnum - sequm_2) order by month) as x

Answer (score 0):

Since the dataset is SET BY record_id it seems very likely to be sorted by that column.  As such something like this would produce the output you're looking for.

```
select record_id, month, status, 
       x=row_number() over (partition by record_id, status order by month)
from t;
```